# How does an OpenGL application bypass X and render directly to GPU? Can I do that?

Tags: linux, x11, graphics, gpu, opengl

I'm trying to understand how this works. So there are 2 types of applications - X apps and OpenGL apps. X apps draw to the screen using Xlib but do OpenGL somehow bypass X completely and render directly to the GPU? How does it do that?

If both X and OpenGL are running - how does my computer know which one to render to the screen? Is there some priority level? While X is running, can I bypass it and draw over it? That seems to be what OpenGL apps are doing if I understand it correctly.

Comment: There are some nice diagrams on wikipedia [aiglx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIGLX) showing the progression of direct rendering. It needs a Direct Rendering Manager, see [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager).

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL apps do not "bypass X", they ask X to provide a surface, and draw on it. Then X decides how to project that surface to the screen. Sometimes, if the app has frozen, you can see the surface when moving the windows, as a bright green rectangle.

You could draw directly on the screen before. However, now we have compositing window managers which, in a sense, do it themselves. So, while the API to draw on screen is likely still available, the WM will simply overpaint your stuff, 60 times per second.

Comment: Well according to this, OpenGL apps like 3D games do not use X - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZSjs.png

Comment: Also according to this https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/x-org-drm/4629-what-is-x-org-x11-gallium3d-mesa-etc - "rendering can be done in two ways -- "indirect" through the same X protocol as text and 2d graphics, or "direct" which bypasses the X protocol and lets the application talk directly to the graphics driver."